# How to count number of 0 in a list of lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, web-scraping, count

I want calculate the number of time a 0 appears in a "list of lists" web scraped, it's like my `list` of lists is not a `list` because when I print, it's done that :

```
[3]
[1]
[3]
[3]
[1]
[1]
[0]
[0]
[1]
[1]
```

if it's really is a list of list it's should tell me this :

```
[[3],[1],[3],[3],[1],[1],[0],[0],[1],[1]]
```

So, `list` or not `list` I cant count the number of time the 0 is here, how can I do for count the 0 ?

In this exemple, there is two 0, so the result is = 2

There is my code, maybe you can tell me how I can, I tried count(0) and other method, but it's dont work

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from csv import writer

url= "https://blablablabla.htm"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

lists = soup.find_all('tr', class_="mat1")

with open('file.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8', newline='') as f:
    thewriter = writer(f)

for list in lists: 
        
        but = list.find('td', class_="tj1").text.replace('\xa0', '').replace(" ", "1")
        
        info = but[3:]

        infos = len(info)
        infoss = int(infos)
        print(infoss)
```

print(infoss) is :

```
3
1
3
3
1
1
0
0
1
1
```

and i need a code which tell me the number of 0 in this list, so here it's 2

Comment: As a good rule of thumb, don't name variables things that are something else. `list` is already a predefined thing in Python, so if you name a variable that it cannot call that predefined thing. It is better to name it `_list`, or `l`, or something else entirely.

Comment: thanks a lot, i didnt know that, i tried rename all the list with _list or l , but it's doesnt change, the result is the same...

Comment: please don't use `list` as a name (variable). You will overwrite the in-built - in this case when you reference inside the for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already iterating through the list of lists and printing out the values within it.

Can you think of a way to check the value instead of printing it and keep track of the number of times the value is equal to 0?

EDIT: Are you saying that this code doesn't work?

```
import requests
from csv import writer

url= "https://blablablabla.htm"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

lists = soup.find_all('tr', class_="mat1")

with open('file.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8', newline='') as f:
    thewriter = writer(f)

coun = 0
for list in lists: 
        
        but = list.find('td', class_="tj1").text.replace('\xa0', '').replace(" ", "1")
        
        info = but[3:]

        infos = len(info)
        infoss = int(infos)
        print(infoss)
        
        if infoss == 0 :
            coun = coun + 1
        

print(coun)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, i print just for showing you, i would like a way to check the value to track the number of time the 0 appear, but what i try didnt work, maybe it's look easy for you guys, but i tried number of method and cant find a solution

Comment: Can you share some of the solutions you tried already?

Comment: No problem. I hope you understand that you were very close to getting the optimal solution.


`coun = 0` needs to be outside of the for loop, otherwise `coun` will reset every time you go through another list

Comment: This link might help you understand why `coun` needed to be outside of the for loop: https://techvidvan.com/tutorials/python-variable-scope/

Answer (score 0):

i tried this :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from csv import writer

url= "https://blablablabla.htm"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

lists = soup.find_all('tr', class_="mat1")

with open('file.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8', newline='') as f:
    thewriter = writer(f)

for list in lists: 
        
        but = list.find('td', class_="tj1").text.replace('\xa0', '').replace(" ", "1")
        
        info = but[3:]

        infos = len(info)
        infoss = int(infos)
        print(infoss)
        
        coun = 0
        if infoss < 1 :
            coun = coun + 1
        
        print(coun)
```

the result is this :

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
1
0
0
```

yes it's tell me 1 and 1, but i dont want that form of answer, i just want it's tell me result = 2, without all the rest

i tried to just have the number of item with a len, but it's seems to me, it's a bunch of list, but they are not in big list as they should to be. I cant track nothing, they seems not linked betwwen them in a big list.

I tried a dico method, and doesnt work too

Comment: If you move `coun = 0` outside of the for loop, you'll get exactly what you want

Comment: i tried to move outside of the loop, and this didnt work, it's take only the last number of the list, and so the result is = 0 , it's seems it's doesnt "save" the list outside the loop

Comment: I edited my original answer, see if that works

Answer (score 0):

You were close to your goal and based on question title and your second example you could also use a `list comprehension` iterating your `list` and check the `len()` of result:

```
ls = [[3],[1],[3],[3],[1],[1],[0],[0],[1],[1]]
len([l for l in ls if l[0] == 0])
#output -> 2
```

**Note:** *Avoid using `python` reserved terms ([`keywords`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords)), this could have unwanted effects on the results of your code.*

Answer (score -1):

You could try creating new list to store value of `infoss` then count element `infoss` that has 0.

```
lst_infoss = []
for list in lists: 
    
    but = list.find('td', class_="tj1").text.replace('\xa0', '').replace(" ", "1")
    
    info = but[3:]

    infos = len(info)
    infoss = int(infos)
    print(infoss)
    # append infoss to new list (lst_infoss)
    lst_infoss.append(infoss)

print(lst_infoss)    
zero_infoss = lst_infoss.count(0)
print(zero_infoss)
```

Comment: This is also a valid answer, except you are going through the extra steps of adding the element to a list and then counting the values afterwards. Your code already goes through all of the elements once when you do `lst_infoss.append(infoss)`, so there is no need to do that another time like your code does when you do `zero_infoss = lst_infoss.count(0)`. It would make more sense to just keep track of every time `infoss == 0`